# What to test when using TDD in an MVC project

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I'm following a TDD workflow, in an MVC project, but all I can test now are models (entities), but when it comes to controllers I'm more interessted in Behavior than unit testing. Is there a problem using TDD and BDD in the same project ? and are models the only place where we use unit testing ?
Thank you.

Comment: 1) There are no problems using both TDD and BDD, and you probably should always use both. 2) You should certainly unit test controllers and any helper classes as well

Comment: @MarkBaker, I overlooked testing the controllers, I'll keep it in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not only that there is no problem to use TDD and BDD but it is highly recomended. They complement each other well with TDD taking care of unit level and BDD covering behaviours, functionalities and integration. TDD is more dev oriented while BDD brings additional value of bringing all stakeholders together.